# Why I get error usage command amazon cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services

¿How are you?

I'm trying to use this command in Amazon CLI:

```
aws autoscaling describe-launch-configurations \
--query "LaunchConfigurations[?contains(LaunchConfigurationName,'Extra')].LaunchConfigurationName\
                                                                             | sort_by(LaunchConfigurations, &CreatedTime)[0].[CreatedTime,LaunchConfigurationName]
```

But I have an error:

In function sort_by(), invalid type for value: None, expected one of: ['array'], received: "null"

In the first part, I get a list of Launch configuration on Amazon EC2. Why in sort_by, I receive a null output?

When I execute the command without sort_by, I don't have any problem....

Comment: What if you execute only the sort?
```aws autoscaling describe-launch-configurations \
--query "sort_by(LaunchConfigurations, &CreatedTime)[0].[CreatedTime,LaunchConfigurationName]"```

Comment: Can someone enlighten me, that this has to do with Groovy?

Comment: @Lucasz I need filter over two Launches configurations in AWS EC2

Answer (score 0):

if your list returned by the query contains no results. the sort command will respond 'null'

Comment: I do that in jenkins:

`   def jsonLaunchConfig = sshCommand remote: remote, command: '''aws autoscaling describe-launch-configurations \
                                                                                --query "LaunchConfigurations[?contains(LaunchConfigurationName,'LCA')]\
                                                                                | sort_by(@, &CreatedTime)[0].{LaunchConfigurationName:LaunchConfigurationName}`  and it worked with JMESpath https://jmespath.org/specification.html